# Group By Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I have a two tables called "Orders" and "OrderItems" and they have the following columns

### Orders

OrderId,
OrderDate,
OrderType,

### OrderItems

ItemId,
OrderId,
Price,

I need to return the OrderId, OrderDate, OrderType and the Sum Of the Price. However I can't seem to find a good example of how to do this in linq to entities.

Can anyone help?

EDIT

Just to be clear, I need show one line for each order with the price being the sum of all the order items for that order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say there are 3 orders IDs: 1,2,3
and there are 3 order items as mentioned below:

- ID=1, OrderID=1 ,Price=12
- ID=2, OrderID=1 ,Price=13
- ID=3, OrderID=3 ,Price=14

  ```
  var carts = (from Cart o in Context.Orders
             join oi in Context.OrderItems on o.Id equals oi.OrderId into orderItems
             select new 
             {
                 o.Id,
                 o.OrderDate,
                 o.OrderType,
                 sum = orderItems.Sum(p=> p.Price)
             }).ToList();
  ```

The linq mentioned above will select sum as mentioned below

- OrderID: 1, Sum:25
- OrderID: 2, Sum:0
- OrderID: 3, Sum:14

Comment: This sums the total price of all items not the just price of the order lines. I have edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: Nope..This will sum the items based on OrderId. Each order will have individual sum of price of its items.

Comment: Many Apologies. I read your answer wrong. It works fine thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
context.Orders.Include(order => order.OrderItems).Select(order => new {
    OrderId = order.OrderId,
    OrderDate = order.OrderDate,
    Ordertype = order.OrderType,
    TotalPrice = i.OrderItems.Sum(orderItem => orderItem.Price)
});
```

Maybe you could try something like this.